# Nontrivial example of an artin algebra R such that R is pure-injective as an R-module

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, commutative-algebra, representation-theory, homological-algebra

> Give a nontrivial example of an artin algebra $R$ such that $R$ is pure-injective as an $R$-module.

Clearly $0$-Gorenstein (self-injective) artin algebra has this property.
Can anyone give me a nontrivial example? Thanks!

**Edit.** R. Goebel, J. Trlifaj's book *Approximations and Endomorphism Algebras of Modules* in Corollary 1.2.22 says over an artin algebra $R$, $R$ is always pure-injective as a left $R$-module. Thanks for all helpful discussions.

Answer (score 1):

According to Corollary 4.2 of Leif Melkersson's paper [Cohomological Properties of Modules with Secondary Representations](http://www.mscand.dk/article/view/12561/10577), any Artinian module over a commutative Noetherian ring is pure injective.  In particular, any commutative Artinian ring is pure injective over itself, since Artinian rings are Noetherian by the Hopkins-Levitzki theorem.

An example which is not self-injective is given by $K[x,y]/(x^2, y^2, xy)$, for any field $K$.

Comment: Nice! For those who don't have access to the paper: the claim is reduced to the case of a complete local ring first, where by Matlis duality any Artinian module is of the form $\text{Hom}(M,E)$ for $M$ a finitely generated module and $E$ the injective hull of the residue field. Now it follows directly from the definition of pure injectivity that firstly any injective is pure-injective and secondly that with any pure-injective $I$ also $\text{Hom}(N,I)$ is pure-injective for any module $N$.

Comment: @Hanno Thank you for this nice summary! I hadn't realized that the access to the paper was restricted.

Comment: There is no restriction to that paper.